# How to enter input data from an Excel to a Selenium project?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I would like your support by providing information (scripts, videos, or books) regarding how to enter input data (for example: username and password) to a selenium project from an Excel file using Cucumber and Serenity DB.

Is it possible?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Thalia Depaz. Here is the link which will help you. [Serenity Test Data from CSV](http://serenity-bdd.info/docs/serenity/#_using_test_data_from_csv_files)

Answer (score 1):

By principle, Cucumber doesn't supports data from external files. Instead it encourages to provide examples with scenario. However there are few non standard way available with cucumber to use examples from the external file. One of them, you can refer in [grasshopper's post](http://grasshopper.tech/418/).

Another alternate is using [gherkin with QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) which provides lots of features inbuilt [data-providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) including XML/CSV/JSON/EXCEL/DB. Here is the [step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQ](https://docs.cucumber.io/community/faq/#how-can-i-specify-my-test-cases-in-excel-csv):

"We advise you not to use Excel or csv files to define your test cases; using Excel or csv files is considered an anti-pattern.

One of the goals of Cucumber is to have executable specifications. This means your feature files should contain just the right level of information to document the expected behaviour of the system. If your test cases are kept in separate files, how would you be able to read the documentation?

This also means you shouldn’t have too many details in your feature file. If you do, you might consider moving them to your step definitions or [helper methods](https://docs.cucumber.io/community/faq/#how-to-use-helper-methods). For instance, if you have a form where you need to populate lots of different fields, you might use the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to do so."